# What does "closed" mean in relation to vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

I am reading a book on Matrix Algebra and saw this:
[image]

What does "closed" mean?  The author has not defined that term.

Comment: A collection of objects is **closed** with respect to a certain *operation* if every application of the operation to objects in the collection will produce a result that belongs to the same collection. Natural numbers are **closed** with respect to sum and product (and not with respect to subtraction).

Answer (score 1):

The term "closed" has more than one meaning, in different fields (e.g. in topology/analysis). In this case, a set $A$ is "closed" under a particular construction if, given any object(s) in $A$, then performing the construction with these objects will produce something also in $A$.

We have a classic example in linear algebra. We often talk about a "subspace" $W$ of a given vector space $V$. We require $W$ to be non-empty, *closed under addition* (meaning, for all $v, w \in W$, we also have $v + w \in W$) and *closed under scalar multiplication* (meaning, for all $w \in W$ and $\lambda$ in the scalar field, then $\lambda w \in W$).

In this case, a subset $C$ of a real vector space is *closed under convex combinations* if every convex combination of vectors in $C$ is also a vector in $C$. That is, given any $v, w \in C$, and any real numbers $a, b \ge 0$ such that $a + b = 1$, we have $av + bw \in C$.

Answer (score 0):

It means  closed w.r.t. the operation of taking convex combinations:  $ax+by \in S$ for all $x,y \in S$ and all $a,b \ge 0$ with $a+b=1$ where $S$ is the given set.